# overlapping Gate pulses(switched reluctance motor)

Tags: motor, motor-controller

[image]
I am trying to simulate 6/4 SRM motor in Simulink by manually giving the gate pulses to each of the phase(Open loop configuration). The problem is for a duty cycle of 25% the gate pulses don't overlap with each other and the output I am getting is okayish. But when I am increasing the duty cycle (40% in the figure) the pulses start to overlap and therefore i am not getting the proper output.
How do I generate pulses so that they don't overlap?